# Twitter API Request for User List Statuses Authentication

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the Twitter API to retrieve a Twitter list for a user. On my local machine the request works, however on my hosting I am getting rate limiting so it requires authentication.

Is there a straightforward and EASY method to authenticate a request. I have registered my application with Twitter but is it necessary to jump through a million hoops to authenticate a request. The original request is as follows:

http://api.twitter.com/1/kevwalker/lists/football/statuses.atom?per_page=50

Any help or articles most appreciated as I need this pretty quickly. My application is written in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to necessarily register your application to use the Twitter API. It also depends on the request weather or not it's rate limited or if you need to authenticate at all. For requests that are rate limited, one thing I'm doing in my own Twitter application is forwarding the request to the user client side then receiving the data back server side. That way the burden is never on my server and the rate limit problem is effectively solved because the user is requesting the data instead of my server requesting it. You can also try caching the results if that scenario works in your case. Poll a request periodically and whenever a user asks for the request, instead of hitting the API - have them hit your cached data.

Take a look at the [Rate Limiting doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) for Twitter's own take on the subject

Every method in the Twitter API also lists if it requires authentication or if it's being rate limited. Look at each [API method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/statuses) where it lists this information. For example in your case, your requesting list statuses and this does not need authentication unless you are wanting to get the authenticating users lists, instead of accessing them directly like you are in your example.

You might also find the [rate limit API](http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.xml) helpful.